# Convert character string to date format

Tags: sas

Im trying to convert a character string of $40. to date format.
below is the column Month in the dataset test2 and its values:

```
Month
Apr 15
May 15
Jun 15
```

I have tried this code but not getting the result I'm expecting.

```
data test;
  set test2;
  Month =inPUT(month,monyy5.);
/*  Mon=input(month,8.);*/
/*  format month $MonYY5.;*/
run;
```

Thank you

Comment: I got the solution guys. It is may be because I'm trying to use same column name but when I used different column name, it is working.

Comment: You should write the answer below and select it as the answer yourself.

Comment: You can't change the type of a column name directly, which is why your code didn't work.  To keep the same column name, you need to create a new one, drop the old one, then rename the new one to the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 data test(Rename=(MM=Month));
   set test2;
   MM =inPUT(Month,monyy5.);
 format MM $MonYY5.;
 Drop MM;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

please, apply the input to a new column as you can't directly change the type of a column (char to num).

```
data test2; length mm $10; mm='APR15'; output; mm='MAY14'; output; run;

data test (rename=(_mm=mm));
set test2;
_mm=input(mm,monyy5.);
format _mm monyy.;
drop mm;
run;
```